# Activate/Deactivate Apex Trigger using custom object configuration

Tags: apex, trigger

I need to control whether a trigger can execute or not without using the standard salesforce checkbox in each of the trigger's page. 
I have a custom object populated with the trigger ids present in an instance and have a custom field set against each of the trigger id stating active or inactive. But from within the trigger i am unable to query that object because i do not know the id of the trigger which is executing. If i could find the trigger id, i can check against that object and find if this trigger can execute or not.

Any solution or workaround for this will be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I ended up building a custom .net application to fetch list of triggers from an org and providing the users with a form to activate and deactivate any trigger(s). Finally i am updating the metadata information back to SF using Metadata API Deploy() methods. Thanks andrew, Fernando and crmprogdev for your suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

**Querying for Apex Triggers:** In answer to your question you can execute the following to list the triggers associated with the object being operated on. The only context you have is the object itself however, so you may need to add further criteria to the query to narrow it down to your specific trigger.

```
// Query ApexTriggers for this object (add NamespacePrefix or Name criteria to narrow this search)
String triggerSObjectName = 
    Trigger.isInsert ?
        Trigger.new[0].getSObjectType().getDescribe().name :
        Trigger.old[0].getSObjectType().getDescribe().name;
List<ApexTrigger> triggersForThisObject = 
    [select Id, Name from ApexTrigger where TableEnumOrId = :triggerSObjectName ];
System.debug('First trigger Id ' + triggersForThisObject[0].Id);
```

**Another Consideration:** Since you have to add the code to disable the trigger, have you considered using the trigger name (as a convention) instead of its ID. Then using a **Custom Setting** instead of a Custom Object. Which will be not use any SOQL queries. Further more (optionally) if your creating a managed package, a protected custom setting is only visible to your support team, and thus admins cannot disable.

The following trigger code sample below uses a List based Custom Setting.

```
trigger TestTrigger on Test__c (before insert, before delete) {

    if(TriggerControl__c.getValues('TestTrigger') != null)
        return;
```

This custom setting does not have any fields beyond the Name field. So long as a record exists with the appropriate name the above code will disable the trigger. You could extend this with other fields that control your trigger behaviours.

[image]

Comment: I thought of using the custom settings but again from the trigger context I would be able to get the sObject alone. And if there are quite a few triggers on the same sObject then I will be unable to get the correct trigger name that fired.

Comment: Yes use of a Custom Setting does not address the need to know specifically which trigger it is. I am afraid you will only be able to determine the list of triggers on an object. However surely if you are writing the trigger logic you can key on anything you like, it does not have to be the Id? Why not the Trigger name and Namespace? Unless I am missing something. It might help perhaps to paste a bit of your trigger code, just in case I'm not getting the full picture. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a checkbox on a visualforce page to include a boolean object that you can activate or deactivate at will to turn your trigger on or off. There's no need to link it to the trigger Id, just link it to the custom object. You can then turn on and off at will by changing the default value for the boolean object. It won't be visible in the trigger's on/off checkbox but will be readily controllable.

You could also easily place links to all of the boolean objects to one custom VF page to control each of your triggers. That would be the easiest workaround to what you describe that I know of if I'm correctly understanding your question. You also wouldn't have to go through any unit testing when you wanted to turn a trigger back on in a production environment.

This type of strategy is used for central control of multiple triggers that act on the same object, centralized diagnostics, and tracking of @future calls as described in Dan Appleman's book Advanced Apex Programming.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your idea, should I just place hyperlinks to the triggers in a VF page and then redirect to the trigger on clicking and edit the isActive checkbox there.

Comment: @Ganesh Sridhar. No, what you would do is create links to the custom boolean objects that control whether or not each of the triggers function. In essence, it would be the same as having a **hidden checkbox** on the VF page for the object a trigger acts on that you control on a separate page. The trigger remains active, but does nothing, because it first checks for the boolean condition of true or false. If false, it simply exits. Your custom VF page toggles the custom boolean objects for each trigger between true and false all in one place. The triggers themselves always remain active.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in this article can be used to implement that mechanism in a trigger.
This way you can disable the trigger on a per user basis.

http://learnsf.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/disable-validation-rules-4-data-load/

Answer (score 0):

GearsCRM has a free (yup that's $0) managed package that implements Trigger Architecture via configuration (using Custom Meta Data Types).  The configuration allows for control over events, active versus inactive, execution order, recursion, and so much more.

http://gearscrm.com/about/apex-development-approach/trigger-architecture-faqs/trigger-architecture-resources/trigger-architecture-downloads/

Comment: This post seems borderline spam. Can you at least disclose any affiliation you have with this product, and maybe include some sort of brief introduction to how it works?