# Stop triggers before dml

Tags: apex

I have to stop all the triggers while doing a DML operation(upsert) in the apex, for that, I have one checkbox in custom settings to stop all the triggers. Before doing DML operation, I am setting the checkbox true but I don't want to update it in custom settings, so it's not working.

```
if(eventList!= null && eventList.size()>0){
    appSettings.Stop_Package_Default_Triggers__c = true;
    Schema.SObjectField externalIdField = 
        Event.Fields.LeadSquared_Activity_Id__c ;
    Database.UpsertResult [] upsertEventList = 
        Database.upsert(eventList, externalIdField, false);
}
```

Please tell me how to achieve it?

Comment: Can you please show us your code so far so we can take a look at it?. It looks like you need to set some static logic but it would be nice to see your code first.

Comment: if(eventList!= null && eventList.size()>0){
                 appSettings.Stop_Package_Default_Triggers__c = true;
                 Schema.SObjectField externalIdField = Event.Fields.LeadSquared_Activity_Id__c ;
                 Database.UpsertResult [] upsertEventList = Database.upsert(eventList, externalIdField, false);

Answer (score 1):

First thing in trigger should be your check if custom setting is `on`. Here is an example:

```
trigger ***TriggerName*** on ObjectName (trigger_events) {

    if(appSettings.Stop_Package_Default_Triggers__c) {
        // your actual logic starts

        if(your_events) {
            // code_block
        }
    }
}
```

Some references to blogs and similar questions:

1. [Disabling Trigger Events in Apex Enterprise Patterns](https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/04/13/disabling-trigger-events-in-apex-enterprise-patterns/)
2. [Activate/Deactivate Apex Trigger using custom object configuration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10200/activate-deactivate-apex-trigger-using-custom-object-configuration)
3. [Turn Triggers On and Off with Custom Settings.](https://jkilburn2043.wordpress.com/2015/10/06/turn-triggers-on-and-off-with-custom-settings/)